# How can I batch print photos with the 'Scale to fit media' checkbox enabled?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, automation, batch-processing

If I run through an action with record on and in the following steps:

- Start record
- Print
- Set 'Scale to fit media' to checked
- Click the print button
- Then configure the printer settings
- Click print again on the printer popup window
- End record
- File > Automate > Batch > Select Currently open files and the recently created action.
- Run

The action prints out a bunch of images that are printed way to big for the paper which means that the checkbox setting is not being recorded when I start my action.

**This is what my image looks like**
[image: My open photo in Photoshop]

**This is what the image looks like in the print dialogue box**
[image: What the photo looks like in the print dialogue box]

**This is what I want the image to look like every time I play my action (with the checkbox inside the red box checked)**
[image]

Is there a way for me to make it so that it does record this element of the action?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of.

I'd scale the image before printing to fit the media (make the scaling part of your action), then print. You can do the scaling at IMAGE > IMAGE SIZE...

Comment: While this workaround doesn't technically answer the question, it is probably the best way to go. Upvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a printer preference, not a Photoshop preference. In order to set printer default options, you will need to open the printer's settings from outside of Photoshop (System Preferences) and set that check box.